# AsyncFileupload Running Javascript from backend

Tags: c#, vb.net, scriptmanager, registerstartupscript

I'm trying to run a `JavaScript` function upon my `AsyncFileUpload` `UploadComplete` function.

I am using the `ScriptManager` to register a new script using:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Page.GetType, "Script", "UploadError('test', 'test');", True).
```

I have a function declared in my `JS` file named `UploadError`:

```
function UploadError(div, message) {
    alert("1");
    $("#viderror").fadeIn();
    alert("got here")
}
```

The two alerts fire but the `$("#viderror")` does not fade in.  The above function is my attempt at trying to debug why events other than alerts are not firing.  Basically what I am trying to do is run a function that will display an error determined by the back end based on file size, file type, etc.

Does anyone have any idea why `javascript` events other then alerts are not working?

Thanks

Comment: use the F12 dev tools in the browser to look at the console for errors. Is JQuery loaded? Does elelment #viderror exist in the dom?

Comment: It is visible yes, and there are no errors regarding that.  I am using jQuery pretty extensively on the page for ajax calls so jQuery is definitely loaded. I think it must have something to do with the AsyncFileUpload and how it doesn't refresh the whole page, but i am unsure of how to fix it.  I have also tried manipulating the element using pure javascript but it does not work either.

Comment: Perhaps, adding `javascript` tag will help your question get notified.